# Rhythmbox how to add entry to side pane?

Tags: python, plugins, gtk, gnome, rhythmbox

I'm trying to write a Rhythmbox plugin and would need to add another entry in the left panel that allows the user to switch to a new "page" provided by my plugin. Unhappily the only ressource I could find about writing RB plugins is [this](http://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/WritingGuide) and I am unable to figure it out just with that.

I am **not** an experienced GTK developer, but I know the basics.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to add a new item to the source panel in Rhythmbox.

You need to subclass `RB.Source` and register it with gobject using `gobject.type_register(ClassName)`.

Here is an [example](http://vega.frugalware.org/tmpgit/rhythmbox-0.13.3/plugins/sample-python/sample-python.py) which uses the new `gi.repository` and there are plenty that [don't](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22RB%20Source%22%20inurl%3apy%20rhythmbox).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know some places where I can get references / tutorials about rhythmbox plugins?
Note that the example plugin returns the following error:
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.RB' object has no attribute 'Plugin'

Answer (score 0):

Read section ["Adding UI somewhere other than toolbars and menus"](http://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/WritingGuide#Adding_UI_somewhere_other_than_toolbars_and_menus) in that link you mentioned.

Comment: I would not have posted a question if I would have been able to solve the problem with the reference(s) I found. I've gone through that text ofte. Either it does not contain the info I want or, more probably, I just didn't get it (Or I tried it and it didn't work).